# Lost CD Key after repair install of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, product-key

So I needed to re-install Windows 7 HP x64 on a customer's computer, and stupid me forgot to retrieve the CD key before doing so. Now, the CD key put in there is getting told it's invalid, and Windows is not genuine. I have access to the Inplace Upgrade folder and the old Windows folder, but the SOFTWARE registry key looks to be missing, so I can't seem to use a keyfinder. Is there something I'm missing here, or do I need to shell out some money for another key?

Comment: If your customer has a license, he *must have* the key somewhere. Maybe a sticker on the computer? If he bought windows separately, it must be somewhere near the dvd. If not, why should *you* bother legalizing his windows?

Comment: Is the `SOFTWARE` hive the one with the encoded key or is it in the `SYSTEM` hive?

Comment: In the old Windows\System32\config folder, it has the hives there but they're in a TSF format, which I've never seen, so key finders don't seem to want to work on it. Also @Ranon, I believe you're right. There's a Vista sticker on it, and he had a genuine copy of 7 before cause he was running MSE

Comment: @Luke You only need a genuine copy to download MSE, I don't think it checks on install.

Comment: It checks constantly

Comment: Was this system originally Windows 7 from HP? If so you can order a recovery disc set, then you don't need a key, it will install one automatically during recovery...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00810334&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

Comment: No, came with Vista

Comment: Then where did they get Windows 7 from?

Comment: I am assuming it was bought. I'm not looking for excuses not to, I'm looking for info on if the key would have been saved anywhere